# Free ornaments font

Tags: fonts, symbols

I'm looking for a free ornaments font. I know about [`webomint`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/webomints/) and `pifont`. Where can I find more glyphs?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31807/where-i-can-find-examples-of-decorated-borders-margins/31813#31813

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can't miss adforn font. Use `\usepackage{adforn}` to access the glyphs. See [manual of the package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/adforn/doc/fonts/adforn/adforn.pdf) for the commands.

[image: font table]

There are still other fonts including ornaments (not in *The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List*), for example, linux-libertine (`libertine` package).

Answer (score 30):

[`fourier`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fourier) offers ornamental glyphs, specifically `fourier-orns`. A short example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\textxswup\textxswdown
\decoone\decotwo
\decothreeleft\decothreeright
\decofourleft\decofourright
\floweroneleft\floweroneright
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are more, have a look at the [fourier-orns example](https://ctan.joethei.xyz/fonts/fourier-GUT/doc//fourier-orns-doc.pdf) pdf file.

Answer (score 16):

There is also `pgfornament`. This is not a font - any more than `pst-vectorian` is a font. Rather, it consists of code for drawing ornaments using PGF.

While not on CTAN, it is readily available and, I think, quite popular because, unlike its `pst-` predecessor, it can be straightforwardly used with pdfTeX. It is available as [pgfornament.zip](http://www.altermundus.com/pages/downloads/packages/pgfornament/pgfornament.zip).

A sampler:

[image: PGF 'vectorian' ornaments]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfornament}

\begin{document}
  \tikzset{
    pgfornamentstyle/.style={scale=.25}
  }
  \foreach \i in {1,...,89} {\expandafter\pgfornament\expandafter{\i}\ }
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is on CTAN now: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfornament

Answer (score 9):

If you are using XeTeX or LuaTeX, you can use anything from [Font Squirrel's dingbat list](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/style/Dingbat), which lists some nice ones.

Comment: A notable font not available from Font Squirrel is [Florea](http://www.leabhair.ie/clonna-en.html).

Answer (score 7):

`umrandb` and `umranda` are not listed here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\section{umranda}
\fonttable{umranda}
\subsection{Usage}
\verb|\font\umranda=umranda \umranda  \char35 --- | \font\umranda=umranda
\umranda  \char35
%
\newpage
\section{umrandb}
\fonttable{umrandb}
\subsection{Usage}
\verb|\font\umrandb=umrandb \umrandb  \char114 --- | \font\umrandb=umrandb
\umrandb  \char114
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think that [pst-vectorian](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-vectorian) really needs a shout-out here.  It's got some stunning ornaments.

The [DRM](http://ctan.org/pkg/drm) font also has some interesting ornamental possibilities.  (Disclaimer:  I'm the author of DRM, and my opinion of it is correspondingly biased.)

Both have demonstrative documentation.

Comment: As this is the answer that made me look at DRM, I'll try asking here: I keep getting an error that `tilde' is already defined when I try to use DRM. I looked at the only other question that _kinda_ is related (unless I simply did not search correctly) [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239178/command-unavailable-in-encoding-eu1-when-using-unicode-math], but it didn't help. I'm using XeLaTeX, could this be the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: XeLaTeX might be the problem; I've never seen that error in pdflatex or lualatex.  I'm sorry; I wish I could help.

Comment: Would you recommend switching to LuaLaTeX in general? I switch fonts quite a lot, which is why I opted for XeLaTeX in the first place. Does LuaLaTeX offer the same convenience there?

Comment: It's hard to say.  Personally, I do use Lualatex occasionally, but I've never really exhausted the abilities of pdflatex, and I've never used xelatex.  As I understand it, lualatex incorporates all of xelatex's font-related advances (particularly through `fontspec`), but I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List (PDF 358 pages) by Scott Pakin https://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive

Answer (score 0):

The `novel` package contains a font `NovelDeco.otf`, which includes a small number of ornaments designed for such places as underneath chapter titles, in a work of fiction. The decorations are not for math. SIL Open Font License, so you can use the font in commercial works.

Since `fontspec` is required to access the Open Type characters, you need to compile with LuaLaTeX (maybe XeTeX).

Although the number of decorations is small, they have the advantage of having several weights per glyph. So, you can select lighter weights when the glyphs are shown at larger scales.

If you use `novel` document class, there are special commands for accessing the glyphs. But without using `novel` you can still access the glyphs, using `fontspec`.