# End of paragraph with ornament

Tags: decorations

How to make a line with ornament like one below {TEX} logo on this site?

What is specific term for it?

Comment: Well, Yiannis's answer is the earliest.

Comment: sorry guys, it seems that we all replied more or less at the same time. If you are ok Krule, we can summarise it directly in the question...

Comment: See also [asterism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterism_%28typography%29), and this question, [Asterism and similar breaking / non-breaking options](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160336/29697).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\hrulefill\hspace{0.2cm} \floweroneleft\floweroneright \hspace{0.2cm} \hrulefill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

For fonts of ornament, see question [Free ornaments font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10941/2674).

I raised the line a little.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}

\newcommand\crulefill[1][1ex]{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule depth \dimexpr-#1+0.4pt height #1\hfill\kern0pt}
\newcommand\ornline[2][1ex]{\trivlist\item\crulefill[#1]#2\crulefill[#1]\endtrivlist}
\begin{document}

\ornline{\ding{100}}

\ornline[0.6ex]{\decoone}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But this generates a "line" made from this symbols, doesn't it? I think to OP wants "---- (symbol) ----" instead.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 11):

to have a line with some symbol in the middle, just use

```
\hrulefill WHATEVERSYMBOL \hrulefill
```

You can use the [ornaments cited by Leo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10941/2674). You might also want to add spaces around the ornament:

```
\hrulefill~ WHATEVERSYMBOL~ \hrulefill
```

You might also want to move the symbol around to align it with the rules and avoid the indent:

```
\noindent \hrulefill~ \raisebox{-4pt}[10pt][10pt]{\textxswup}~ \hrulefill
```

Here is what you would get:
[image]

Clearly, you will want to make a new macro to use that more easily.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use "ornements" to make a frame (cadre in french),  some links very interesting in french, you have some sources and some explanations to install fonts :

http://jacques-andre.fr/fontex/ornements-charte.pdf

http://jacques-andre.fr/ed/

http://jacques-andre.fr/faqtypo/orn/

http://jacques-andre.fr/fontex/casseaux.pdf

You can find a lot of documents on this site