# Visual separation when using linerange in listings

Tags: listings

I have read through the `listings` documentation and couldn't find an answer to the following question:
How do I insert some sort of visual feedback in a listings listing when using the `linerange` option. It works fine on my source code files, but the only visible feedback that there is a gap in the listed code is the change in numbering. I would like some more visual feedback, e.g. a line or maybe some sort of waves that I come across in some books on programming.
Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to [split the listings for each line range](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30615/in-listings-how-to-show-referenced-linenumbers-instead-of-standard-ascending-lin/30616#30616), and place an ornament in between them.  There are many options as to what to use as a separator.  To illustrate, I have used an [ornament from this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11320/end-of-paragraph-with-ornament) in between the listings and another from this question on [how to insert a border](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30973/how-do-i-insert-a-border-below-text/30979#30979) at the end of the listings.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}

%------------------------ Used for ornament between listings
% Ornament from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11320/end-of-paragraph-with-ornament
\usepackage{pifont,fourier-orns}% These are needed only for the ornament 

\newcommand\crulefill[1][1ex]{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule depth \dimexpr-#1+0.4pt height #1\hfill\kern0pt}
\newcommand\ornline[2][1ex]{\trivlist\item\crulefill[#1]#2\crulefill[#1]\endtrivlist}

%------------------------ Used for ornament at end of listings
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30973/how-do-i-insert-a-border-below-text/30979#30979
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\myrule}{O{1pt} O{3pt} O{black}}{%
  \par\nobreak % don't break a page here
  \kern\the\prevdepth % don't take into account the depth of the preceding line
  \kern#2 % space before the rule
  {\color{#3}\hrule height #1 width\hsize} % the rule
  \kern#2 % space after the rule
  \nointerlineskip % no additional space after the rule
}
%------------------------

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.java}
 public int nextInt(int n) {
     if (n<=0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");

     if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
         return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

     int bits, val;
     do {
         bits = next(31);
         val = bits % n;
     } while(bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
     return val;
 }
\end{filecontents*}

\lstdefinestyle{MyListStyle} {numbers=left, language=Java}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[style=MyListStyle,linerange={2-6},firstnumber=2]{foo.java}
\ornline[0.6ex]{\decoone}

\lstinputlisting[style=MyListStyle,linerange={9-11},firstnumber=9]{foo.java}
\myrule[5pt][5pt][orange]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, a little late for my thesis but I will definitely use this in my master thesis. Great!