# In listings, how to show referenced linenumbers instead of standard ascending linenumbers

Tags: listings, line-numbering

I'm just writing on my master thesis and have a (specific) problem with `lstlisting` package in LaTeX.

I'm referring to the `Random.class`-file in Java and only want to print some specific line-ranges, which is working fine with following lines for Latex:

```
\lstinputlisting[linerange={62-62,78-81,475-479},breaklines=true,language=Java, caption=Excerpt of Source Code of \texttt{Random}-class, label=list:excerptRandomCode, basicstyle=\ttfamily\tiny, captionpos=b,numbers=left,tabsize=2,float=t]{RandomClass.java}
```

The only problem is now, that this doesn't print the actual line numbers. It's starts with line number 1 and stops with line number 10 (thus as many lines I refer to).

How can I say, that he also prints the lines as I mentioned in the `linerange`?
And it would be nice, if I could add one empty line without any reference between my three excerpts of the code.

Comment: I am a bit late on this, however I think that it can be solved by a combination of adding the code I created for [Creating line numbers in lstlisting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42054/7049). One could create a new environment or the equivalent which parses the `linerange` and in that way insert it consequitively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way to do it is to split into separate `lstinputlisting` commands and use `firstnumber` to set the line number of the first line for the given `linerange`.  Here is an example of showing lines 2-6 and 9-11.  This also provides you with an empty line in between.  It should be possible to write a macro that generates the required `lstinputlisting` commands given a list of line ranges, but that should probably be a separate question as it is more related to macro processing than listings:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.java}
 public int nextInt(int n) {
     if (n<=0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");

     if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
         return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

     int bits, val;
     do {
         bits = next(31);
         val = bits % n;
     } while(bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
     return val;
 }
\end{filecontents*}


\lstdefinestyle{MyListStyle} {
    numbers=left,
    language=Java
    }
\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[
    style=MyListStyle,
    linerange={2-6},
    firstnumber=2,
    ]{foo.java}

\lstinputlisting[
    style=MyListStyle,
    linerange={9-11},
    firstnumber=9,
    ]{foo.java}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This would be great of one could automate the sequence of `linerange={...}` ranges into a sequence of `lstlistings`.

Comment: This was also an idea I had, but I want to refer to his as a whole listing and not to three separate listings (that's why I labelled it with label=list:excerptRandomCode). I think there will be a problem, if I write this label to each listing. Or is there a way to make a \begin{caption?} ... \caption{text}\label{WholeListing}\end{caption?} around this list and refer then to the whole surrounding?

Comment: Wouldn't just captioning the last one work?

Comment: That would work, but now it happens that one of the listings appears on a different page.

Comment: Perhaps putting the listings in a float environment?

Comment: This is like \begin{float}[ht] \end{float}?

Comment: @Markus: You could put the set of listings in a `minipage`: `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} \lstinputlisting[..]{foo} \lstinputlisting[..]{foo} ... \end{minipage}`. The `minipage` will not break across pages, therefore keeping it's contents together.

Comment: Thx Peter and Werner. I solved it with Peters Idea to split the code and found the solution that Werner suggested, even If I cannot "float" the code to top or bottom of the page. But now it looks perfect.