# Custom line numbers in lstlisting environment

Tags: listings, line-numbering

I am using the `lstlisting` environment to display code and it works great, however for my current application I need something like:

```
 line 1;    
 3.1: line 2;     
 line 3;     
 3.1.5: line 4;     
 line 5;
```

e.g. I want numbers on some lines and I have to decide the numbers. I know that I can just type them in like in the above box but it will look very bad as the lines don't match up anymore. I read the lstlisting documentation and it didn't bring anything like this up. Is there some workaround here only more experienced users know?

Comment: Yes I will specify them manually and they are at ad-hoc intervals. I want to do everything by hand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I dont think you can do without some manual labour, if you don't have a system of numbering. However you can trick `listings` to use other values.
For reference it is the counter `lstnumber` which holds the current line number.

So the solution is to do conditional checking with the counter and insert the correct format, or reference.

I have created a macro which collects information on the line number and inserts the correct format upon the line number reached.

```
% Save the original way of printing the number
\let\othelstnumber=\thelstnumber
\def\createlinenumber#1#2{
    \edef\thelstnumber{%
        \unexpanded{%
            \ifnum#1=\value{lstnumber}\relax
              #2%
            \else}%
        \expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\thelstnumber\othelstnumber\fi}%
    }
    \ifx\othelstnumber=\relax\else
      \let\othelstnumber\relax
    \fi
}
```

This macro will consecutively store any information that you wish to replace with the `lstnumber` counter.

So calling:

```
\createlinenumber{105}{3.1}
\createlinenumber{107}{3.1.5}
```

will globally change lines 105 and 107 to 3.1, 3.1.5, respectively.

Thus the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
% Save the original way of printing the number
\let\othelstnumber=\thelstnumber
\def\createlinenumber#1#2{
    \edef\thelstnumber{%
        \unexpanded{%
            \ifnum#1=\value{lstnumber}\relax
              #2%
            \else}%
        \expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\thelstnumber\othelstnumber\fi}%
    }
    \ifx\othelstnumber=\relax\else
      \let\othelstnumber\relax
    \fi
}

\bgroup
\createlinenumber{105}{3.1}
\createlinenumber{107}{3.1.5}
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left,firstnumber=100,numberstyle=\ttfamily]
  begin { empty lines }








  end; { empty lines }
\end{lstlisting}
\egroup

\end{document}
```

will produce:

[image: output]

Notice the use of `\bgroup` and `\egroup` to not being globally changed.

### Only manually selected lines

If you do not wish to display any other than yours provided you simply need to tell `TeX` to discard those. Notice that you **cannot** use `numbers=none` as that will never execute `\thelstnumber`.
Thus the code looks like this:

```
\def\createlinenumber#1#2{
    \edef\thelstnumber{%
        \unexpanded{%
            \ifnum#1=\value{lstnumber}\relax
              #2%
            \fi}%
        \ifx\thelstnumber\relax\else
        \expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\thelstnumber}%
        \fi
    }
}
```

However the above requires an initialisation before first use. You then have to add: `\let\thelstnumber\relax` after the first `\bgroup` but before the first execution of `\createlinenumber`.

As bonus info. This was originally intended for a friends thesis who would love to have `007` printed on page `7`. Hence I of course used it on `\thepage`. :)
I just expanded it to do other things as well.

Comment: This seems to be perfectly what I need. But I need the other numbers to disappear, is that possible too? :-)

Comment: I have updated the answer to include that as well.