# Showing only specific lines using the listings package

Tags: listings, external-files, minted

I am very new to TeX.

My source code is in an external file, let's call it `source.java`, and I use `\lstinputlisting{source.java}`.

1. How could I use only the lines 3-5 for my code listing? (and not the whole file?)
2. How could I use only specific lines, e.g., line {1,3,7,12} in the code listing? (I would use this last example only to show the important lines while I still have a running program in `source.java`.)
3. Could I do the same with the `minted` package?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### 2012-02-01: Updated to allow for adjustment of spacing between subsequent lines.

---

Here is a solution for the first two problems adapted from [In listings, how to show referenced linenumbers instead of standard ascending linenumbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30615/in-listings-how-to-show-referenced-linenumbers-instead-of-standard-ascending-li/30616#30616).

### Syntax:

```
\ShowListingForLineNumber*[percentage]{<line number>}}{<file name>}
```

where:

- `*` adjust space above current line (optinal)
- `[percentage]` = percentage of `\baselineskip` to leave above current line (optional, ignored if `*` is not used). If not specified this is defaults to be `1.0` meaning the entire spacing above is suppressed.
- `<line number>}`  is the line number of which the listing is to be printed
- `<file name>` is the file name of the input file

[image]

### Notes:

- I used the `xparse` package to provide the starred version of the command. If you do not want to include an additional package, please see other methods of [Defining starred versions of commands (* macro)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4386/defining-starred-versions-of-commands)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}% to define star variant of macro
\usepackage{listings}


\begin{filecontents*}{foo.java}
 public int nextInt(int n) {
     if (n<=0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");

     if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
         return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

     int bits, val;
     do {
         bits = next(31);
         val = bits % n;
     } while(bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
     return val;
 }
\end{filecontents*}


\lstdefinestyle{MyListStyle} {
    numbers=left,
    language=Java,
    backgroundcolor={\color{yellow}},
    breaklines=true
    }
\begin{document}
\noindent
Showing line range 3-5:
\lstinputlisting[
    style=MyListStyle,
    linerange={3-5},
    firstnumber=3,
    ]{foo.java}

\bigskip\noindent
Showing lines 1,3,7,12 (note that Line 7 is blank) with starred version between lines 1 and 3 to supress the space and the space before line 12 set to 50\% of the \verb|\baselineskip|:

\NewDocumentCommand{\ShowListingForLineNumber}{s O{1.0} m m}{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\vspace{-#2\baselineskip}}{}
    \lstinputlisting[
            style=MyListStyle,
            linerange={#3-#3},
            firstnumber=#3,
            ]{#4}
}%
\ShowListingForLineNumber{1}{foo.java}
\ShowListingForLineNumber*{3}{foo.java}% supress space before
\ShowListingForLineNumber*[0.5]{7}{foo.java}% supress 50% of the space before
\ShowListingForLineNumber*{12}{foo.java}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One Problem... the solution is really great. But to show single Lines, an additional Space is added in between the Lines, e.g., between the lines 1, 3, 12 there is a blank line each. In my paper this takes quite some additional Space and doesn't look nice...

Comment: You can add a `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` before  a subsequent `ShowListingForLineNumber`. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @mrsteve: Updated solution to provide option for adjustment of interline spacing.