# treating multiple code listings as one figure (listings package)

Tags: listings, external-files, sourcecode

Please note that I am quite new to tex/latex.

For my paper I need to reference specific parts of my source code as one code listing. This allows me to skip specific lines of the source code that are to detailed for a code listing.

My initial [Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42822/showing-only-specific-lines-using-the-listings-package) led me to a solution that almost works.

I have special markes in my source code (like '//#< code:1 >#') to reference the relevant lines. I use multiple listings that look like one listing and add a caption.

There is one problem, though, that my code listing is sometimes continued on the next page (see the code example below). This is the case, because to latex my code listing is actually four separate code listings.

Is there a way to fix this, e.g., to tell latex to treat my 4 different code listings as one?

I am not sure how to describe the problem better, and I hope my code listing is clear. I search online for quite some time, but I could not find anything that would help.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,22pt]{article}
```

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\lstset{rangeprefix=#<\ ,% curly left brace plus space
rangesuffix=\ >#,%
includerangemarker=false,%
escapeinside={@}{\^^M}}% space plus curly right brace

\lstdefinestyle{JStyle} {
    boxpos=c,%
    breaklines=true,%
    showlines=false,%
    numbers=none,%numbers=left,%
    numberstyle=\tiny,%
    firstnumber=1,%
    frame=none,%frame=single,%
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    captionpos=b,%
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.java}
//#< code:1 >#
 public int nextInt(int n) {
//#< end >#
//#< code:2 >#
     if (n<=0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");
//#< end >#
//#< code:3 >#
     if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
         return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);
//#< end >#
//#< code:4 >#
     int bits, val;
     do {
         bits = next(31);
         val = bits % n;
     } while(bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
//#< end >#
//#< code:5 >#
     return val;
 }
//#< end >#
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{empty.java}

\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand*{\ShowListingMarker}[2]{%
    \vspace{-#2\baselineskip}{}
    \lstinputlisting[
      style=JStyle,
      linerange={#1-end},%
      emphstyle={[2]\underbar},%
      ]{foo.java}
}

\newcommand*{\ShowListingMarkerCaption}[4]{%
    \vspace{-#2\baselineskip}{}
    \lstinputlisting[language=Tcl,%
      label=#4,%
      linerange={0-0},%
      caption=#3
      ]{empty.java}
}

\section{Introduction} 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

\section{Methods} 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
\section{Background} 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

\section{Approach A}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

\section{Results}

\ShowListingMarker{code:1}{0}
\ShowListingMarker{code:2}{1}
% code:3 is not shown in the figure, this is the flexibility of the approach!
\ShowListingMarker{code:4}{1}
\ShowListingMarker{code:5}{1}
\ShowListingMarkerCaption{code:5}{1.4}{The Program}{fig:program}

\end{document}

Comment: Your example code doesn't work; I get the error `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \lst@rangebeginprefix.
<to be read again> 
                   <
l.13 escapeinside={@}{\^^M}}
                            % space plus curly right brace`. Please fix the example code.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Your example doesn't works because you made a mistake inside this definition:

```
\lstset{rangeprefix=#<\ ,% curly left brace plus space
rangesuffix=\ >#,%
includerangemarker=false,%
escapeinside={@}{\^^M}}% space plus curly right brace
```

The symbol `#` is a special character inside TeX and must be escape. In  the documentation of listings you will find the following hint:

> **Note** that TeX’s special characters like the curly braces, the space,
>   the percent sign, and such must be escaped with a backslash.

The correct one is:

```
\lstset{rangeprefix=\#<\ ,% curly left brace plus space
rangesuffix=\ >\#,%
includerangemarker=false,%
escapeinside={@}{\^^M}}% space plus curly right brace
```

To prevent your code from being splitting you can simple use the `minipage` environment.

This is well discussed in the question:

[Unbreakable block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/unbreakable-block)

Next improvement is to use the package `caption`. Instead of defining `ShowListingMarkerCaption` you can simple use the command `\captionof{lstlisting}{....}` to get a caption.

The output is:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,22pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\lstset{rangeprefix=\#<\ ,% curly left brace plus space
rangesuffix=\ >\#,%
includerangemarker=false,%
escapeinside={@}{\^^M}}% space plus curly right brace

\lstdefinestyle{JStyle} {
    boxpos=c,%
    breaklines=true,%
    showlines=false,%
    numbers=none,%numbers=left,%
    numberstyle=\tiny,%
    firstnumber=1,%
    frame=none,%frame=single,%
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    captionpos=b,%
    }    

\begin{document}


\begin{filecontents*}{foo.java}
//#< code:1 >#
 public int nextInt(int n) {
//#< end >#
//#< code:2 >#
     if (n<=0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");
//#< end >#
//#< code:3 >#
     if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
         return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);
//#< end >#
//#< code:4 >#
     int bits, val;
     do {
         bits = next(31);
         val = bits % n;
     } while(bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
//#< end >#
//#< code:5 >#
     return val;
 }
//#< end >#
\end{filecontents*}



\newcommand*{\ShowListingMarker}[2]{%
    \vspace{-#2\baselineskip}{}
    \lstinputlisting[
      style=JStyle,
      linerange={#1-end},%
      emphstyle={[2]\underbar},%
      ]{foo.java}
}


\section{Introduction}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.


\section{Methods}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
\section{Background}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.


\section{Approach A}


Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.


\section{Results}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\ShowListingMarker{code:1}{0}
\ShowListingMarker{code:2}{1}
\ShowListingMarker{code:4}{1}
\ShowListingMarker{code:5}{1}

\captionof{lstlisting}{The Program}
\label{fig:program}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```