# highlight lines in listings

Tags: listings, minipage

I have code that i have included into my document using the texcode below

```
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\lstinputlisting[numbers=left,xleftmargin=2em,frame=single,framexleftmargin=2em, breaklines]{codesamples/example2.py}
\caption{Modified \soc\ for R, R' \label{R'}}
\end{minipage}
```

I would like to highlight some of the lines in the output. Is this possible?

Comment: I think the following will help: [Showing only specific lines using the `listings` package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42822/5764). The reason is because you're including your code as an external file and may only want to highlight certain lines.

Comment: @thanks, but this wont work for me, I would like to show all the lines

Comment: There is also another interesting approach: see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15237/highlight-text-in-code-listing-while-also-keeping-syntax-highlighting/49309#49309) from Daniel.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the package [`lstlinebgrd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lstaddons) which extends the package [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings).

Here a simple example which will highlight the third line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{example.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\lstinputlisting[numbers=left,xleftmargin=2em,frame=single,framexleftmargin=2em, breaklines,
linebackgroundcolor={\ifnum\value{lstnumber}=3\color{green}\fi}]{example.tex}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update**

To specify the highlighted lines I provided in the example below a macro `\lstcolorlines` which can be used as an argument of the option `linebackgroundcolor`. The function `\lstcolorlines` is defined with the user interface `xparse` and the modul `clist` provided by `expl3`. The Syntax of the command ist:

```
\lstcolorlines[optional argument: color]{mandatory argumente: line numbers}
```

The example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \lstcolorlines { O{green} m }
{
 \clist_if_in:nVT { #2 } { \the\value{lstnumber} }{ \color{#1} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{example.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World!

Hello World!

Hello World!

\verb+1+
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\lstinputlisting[numbers=left,xleftmargin=2em,frame=single,framexleftmargin=2em, breaklines,
linebackgroundcolor={\lstcolorlines{2,9}}]{example.tex}
\end{minipage}


\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\lstinputlisting[numbers=left,xleftmargin=2em,frame=single,framexleftmargin=2em, breaklines,
linebackgroundcolor={\lstcolorlines[yellow]{2,10}}]{example.tex}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Marco has already pointed to Martin Scharrer's [`lstlinebgrd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lstaddons) package, which I personally use for this purpose. However, the package is still pretty new and if you want or need to refrain from using another package, you could also do this "by hand" (as I did in the past).

The idea is to include the listing in three steps: (1) the part before the highlighted line, (2) the highligted line, and (3) the rest. For (2) you additionally set a background color with `backgroundcolor=<color command>`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{example.c}
int main() {
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return 0;
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xcolor,listings}

\begin{document}
\fbox{
  \begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    \lstset{numbers=left,xleftmargin=2em,breaklines,language=C, aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}
    \lstinputlisting[lastline=1]{example.c}
    \lstinputlisting[backgroundcolor=\color{orange!30},firstline=2,lastline=2, firstnumber=2]{example.c}
    \lstinputlisting[firstline=3, firstnumber=3]{example.c}
  \end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]