# Highlighting specific lines with lstinputlisting

Tags: listings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [highlight lines in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58540/highlight-lines-in-listings)

How can I include a source file with the `listings` package and highlight specific lines (coloured text or coloured background will do)?

Comment: Have a look to [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58543) from [highlight lines in listings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58540/highlight-lines-in-listings).

Comment: Thanks, I missed it. I'm voting to close my question as an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you know which words or sentences you want to highlight, you can use the `emph` and `emphstyle` of the command `lstset`. This is done by hand and not really a trick but it should work.

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
language=bash,% or another depending of your input
emph={[1] word with style 1},
emphstyle=[1]\color{teal},
emph={[2] word with style 2},
emphstyle=[2]\color{violet}\bfseries\slshape,
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not good enough for me, the terms I would highlight also appear elsewhere in the source code and I really need a single line to be highlighted.