# How thick a rule does \hline produce?

Tags: tables, rules

How [thick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32711/totally-sweet-horizontal-rules-in-latex) a [rule](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rules_and_Struts) does [`\hline`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) produce (in a bog-standard `tabular` environment) ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "bog-standard", but rules are usually "0.4pt"

Comment: @A.Ellett Just the default width; does it depend on font-size or something else? Where is that value documented?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default definition of `\hline` in the LaTeX kernel with:

```
\def\hline{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet
   \reserved@a\@xhline}
```

So you can see it has the height `\arrayrulewidth`. The dimension `\arrayrulewidth` is initialed in the LaTeX kernel but without any specifications. This is done by the document class. For the most classes the value is `0.4pt`:

```
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.4\p@}%.4pt
```

Comment: Any idea why `0.4pt` is the default? I always wondered why not `0.3pt` or `0.5pt` :)

Comment: @Xavier: This is a question for David or Frank, but 0.4 pt is the default value of TeX for any `hrule`/`vrule`

Comment: `4pt` or `0.4pt` ?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Probably for Leslie :-) I suspect it's to do with matching the width of the rule with that of the thickness of lines in the font (the usual is the upright of the capital 'I').

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty `0.4pt`. Notice the `.` before `4\p@`. I just corrected the code comment in the answer.

Comment: Is `.4pt` and `0.4pt` (generally) equivalent for (La-)TeX ? Is it ever *not* equivalent ?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty: "generaly" yes, but always no. It depends on the contents. But normally you don't need the leading zero.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Really? When can it not be equivalent (other than if there is code / something else before the `.`)?

Comment: @Xavier: This is the exception ;-)

Comment: The `0.4pt` width is the default TeX uses for `\hrule` or `\vrule`; it's a built-in value, by the way. Specifying `0.4pt` or `.4pt` is equivalent.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel ;)

Comment: @egreg So we need to ask Donald to understand why `0.4pt`? Or is it explained somewhere in the TeXbook? ;)

Comment: @Xavier Probably that was the value Knuth found the best for his rules. Or the most common in the books he analyzed.

Comment: @egreg -- default_rule_thickness is parameter `\sigma_8` (texbook, p.447), so it is drawn from the `.tfm` file of the symbol fonts.  in volume e (computer modern typefaces), p.13, *rule_thickness* for `cmr10` is specified as .4(pt); more explanation of how values for the `cm` parameters were derived appears on the previous page.  i don't believe the "prose" portions of volume e are in distribution (unlike `texbook.tex` and `mfbook.tex'); i know the original book was pasted up, but with the re-issue of the c&t set, this may change; i will ask at the next bug review.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's the default thickness for fraction lines; the default value for `\hrule` and `\vrule` are defined in module 463 of `tex.web`.

Comment: @egreg -- thanks; i searched through volume b for nearly half an hour, but missed that.  however, since don really does value consistency, i'm willing to bet a small amount that the value is based on the setting adopted for fraction lines as i described.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Or the other way around, since `0.4pt` for `\hrule` and `\vrule` is built in.

Comment: @egreg -- remember that don worked on tex/mf/cm simultaneously.  (see "digital typesetting" and conversations in "companion to the papers of donald knuth".)  all "monoline" math symbols are the thickness of *rule_nib*, defined as (vol.e, p.551) "{\bf pickup pencircle} scaled {\it rule\_thickness}; {\it rule.nib $:=$ savepen};", where *rule_thickness* is set to .4pt (see setups for parameter files on pp.32ff, vol.e, where "*rth# := .4pt#*; % assume that rules will come from `cmex10`)". but i'll ask don when i deliver the problem reports later this year.

Answer (score 8):

In module 463 of `tex.web` (the source for “TeX the program”) we find

> Here’s a similar procedure that returns a pointer to a rule node. This routine is called just after TeX has seen `\hrule` or `\vrule`; therefore *cur_cmd* will be either *hrule* or *vrule*. The idea is to store the default rule dimensions in the node, then to override them if ‘`height`’ or ‘`width`’ or ‘`depth`’ specifications are found (in any order).
>
> **define** *default_rule* = 26214 { 0.4 pt }

Thus the default value for rule is 0.4 pt. LaTeX offers the `\rule` interface, which has no default. However the default value of `\arrayrulewidth` in the standard classes is set to 0.4pt, I suppose for compatibility with TeX's rules. The parameter `\arrayrulewidth` is what governs the default value for rules in `tabular` and `array` environments, either produced by the `|` specifier,  `\vline`, `\hline` or `\cline`.