# Problem with custom vertical-alignment and/or length of lines/rules in tabular environment

Tags: tables, spacing, vertical-alignment, rules

As a follow-up to [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122956/how-thick-a-rule-does-hline-produce): In my table / tabular,

- `\cline{1-1}` gives me the correct vertical position but **not** the right **horizontal length** .
- In contrast, `\rule{\mycustomlength}{0.4pt}` gives me the right (horizontal) length but **not** at the correct/desired **vertical position**.

How to solve? How to fine-tune? E.g. by adjusting

- either the **lenght** of `\cline`
- or the **vertical position** of `\rule` *(but **without** introducing uneven line spacing further down ! )*

---

**Edit**

- Do **not** want to change tabular's column widths.
- **Do** want to apply my **custom length** *derived from* a (randomly chosen) **string**, e.g. "blaaaaaa".

---

Here's a generic/random MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newlength{\mycustomlength}
\settowidth\mycustomlength{blaaaaaaaaa}

%\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
aaaaaa &bbbb &ccc\\
 \cline{1-1}
%%%%%
% The full syntax of the command is
% \cmidrule[ wd ]( trim ){a–b}
% \cmidrule[\mylength]{1-1}
dddd &e &f \\
\rule{\mycustomlength}{0.4pt}
\\
dddd &e &f \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting with `\rule{\mylength}{0.4pt}`.  It should be placed along the baseline of the context where it is called from.  But you're not even calling it in your example.  So not sure how to help you.

Comment: Also, I think you mean `\setlength{\mylength}{0.4pt}`.  The way you've written it, you're setting `\mylength` to the length of `0.4pt` as text, not as a measurement.

Comment: @A.Ellett You're right; corrected the MWE. Make more sense now ?

Comment: `\rule...` is not the same thing as an `\hrule` or `\cline`.  The `tabular` environment sees the `\rule...` as something that inhabits a cell in your table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use the definition of cline but patched to add a fixed length rule.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newlength{\mycustomlength}
\settowidth\mycustomlength{blaaaaaaaaa}

%\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\def\mycline#1{\expandafter\my@cline\@cline#1\@nil}

\def\my@cline#1\leaders#2\hfill{%
#1\hfill\leaders#2\hskip\mycustomlength\hfill\kern\z@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
aaaaaa &bbbb &ccc\\
 \cline{1-1}
dddd &e &f \\
\rule{\mycustomlength}{0.4pt}
\\
dddd &e &f \\
\mycline{1-1}
dddd &e &f \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How would you work a similar patch for `\cmidrule`?

Comment: @A.Ellett well cmidrule wiill be a leaders as well somewhere so you could just patch it the same way although probably I wouldn't bother and instead just adjust the vertical spacing in this one to be less like cline (which adds no space between the rows, so can over-print content)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Tried adding `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` but somehow this seem to be conflicting with the above customization... Any ideas how to reconcile 'em ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle found a work-around / answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51489/27721): adding `\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}` *before* `\documentclass{article}`.

Comment: I tried to use `\arrayrulecolor{blue}` (using your `colortbl` pkg) like so `\arrayrulecolor{blue}\mycline{1-1}` but that threw an error (`undefined control sequence` w.r.t. `\arrayrulecolor`). Any way to add colour to the custom 'mycline' ?

Comment: My error might be here: `\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ, xcolor=RGB,table]{mdframed}`. Is that a correct way of loading `colortbl`? That line at least doesn't throw an error...

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty `\usepackage{colortbl}` ?

Comment: made it a separate question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123071/how-to-color-my-custom-lines-rules-in-a-table-contained-by-mdframed

Comment: In theory, `mdframed` should load `xcolor` which in turn should load `colortbl`...

Answer (score 1):

You can make in your table a row of arbitrary height setting `\arraystretch` command to `0` before `\begin{tabular}`. However you will need to use `\strut` in every true row of your table to make its height right.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newlength{\mycustomlength}
\settowidth\mycustomlength{blaaaaaaaaa}

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \strut aaaaaa &bbbb &ccc\\
        \hspace{-\arraycolsep}\rule{\mycustomlength}{0.4pt}\\
        \strut blaaaaaaaaa &e &f
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

`\hspace` shifts line to the left border of the table. However if rule is longer than column, there would be a problem.
To avoid it you can unite all columns in the fake row into one using `multirow` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\newlength{\mycustomlength}
\settowidth\mycustomlength{blaaaaaaaaa}

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \strut aaaaaa &bbbb &ccc\\
        \multicolumn{3}{@{}l@}{\rule{\mycustomlength}{0.4pt}}\\
        \strut dddd &e &f
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Example images:

[image: example]

[image: example 2]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! I added the images for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could redefine the width of the cell.  The `\cline` spans the length of the column and then some.

To start with you can try:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newlength{\mycustomlength}
\settowidth\mycustomlength{blaaaaaaaaa}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}cc}
aaaaaa & bbbb & ccc\\
 \cline{1-1}
blaaaaaaaaa & & \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here `\cline` will be exactly the width of the widest column in your table.  However, there is not buffer between columns.  Contrast this with:

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
aaaaaa & bbbb & ccc\\
 \cline{1-1}
blaaaaaaaaa & & \\
\end{tabular}
```

where you can see that the `\cline` is a bit wider than the longest text in the column.

If you want the buffer but you don't want the `\cline` to extend beyond the width of the widest text in the current column, then you can do something like:

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
aaaaaa & bbbb & ccc\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
blaaaaaaaaa & & \\
\end{tabular}
```

Here's what these three options look like,
[image]

Notice that `\cmidrule` adds some extra vertical spacing that `\cline` doesn't.

Comment: Not an option in my "real" (non-MWE) example.

Answer (score 0):

Of the two alternative routes to a solution to this problem, as outlined in my question above, David's solution addresses the former (adjusting the **length** of `\cline`) while egreg gave the key ingredient to the latter (adjusting the **vertical position** of `\rule`) elsewhere:

- to **use** fractions of `\normalbaselineskip`

<sub>and **not** of `\baselineskip`, because this parameter is **zeroed** in a `tabular` environment.</sub>

Since I want to end up with ***even spacing*** after the "rule intervention" (adding up the fractional line heights to give a whole number), this seems promising and doable, too.

Thanks egreg !

:-)