# PRL style horizontal line in Latex

Tags: diagrams

I want to get the line similar to the one in PRL articles at the end. I don't want to use RevTex but can't figure out a simple way of doing it in Latex. Any help will be appreciated.[image: example of line I want]

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. There is a similar question at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32711/totally-sweet-horizontal-rules-in-latex. None of the examples are identical to your  image, but you could perhaps use [dreamlax' answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32717/586) if you have an image file containing that line.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's an elementary, yet visually similar, approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,lipsum}
\newcommand{\PRLsep}{\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\resizebox{0.3333\linewidth}{1pt}{$\bullet$}}\bigskip}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\PRLsep

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

`\PRLsep` is a scaled/flattened version of `$\bullet$` - 1/3 of `\linewidth` wide and `1pt` tall.

Comment: If you use `\blacklozenge` from `amssymb` (or some black diamond shape, see symbols-a4.pdf) it looks even more alike.

Comment: +1, this look much better than the original line in the published papers, which is a JPEG image.

Comment: We can also put the `\makebox` inside a `center` environment.

Answer (score 7):

I extended the example. Now, you can write a text between the seperator. But it is not perfect. The length measurement of `\blacktriangleleft` gives 7.7778pt, but this includes the white space arround it. So this space is also stretched. The calc-Package is required.

[image]

```
\newlength{\PRLlen}
\newcommand*\PRLsep[1]{\settowidth{\PRLlen}{#1}\advance\PRLlen by -\textwidth\divide\PRLlen by -2\noindent\makebox[\the\PRLlen]{\resizebox{\the\PRLlen}{1pt}{$\blacktriangleleft$}}\raisebox{-.5ex}{#1}\makebox[\the\PRLlen]{\resizebox{\the\PRLlen}{1pt}{$\blacktriangleright$}}\bigskip}
\PRLsep{Text}
```

Comment: Also `amssymb` is required.

Answer (score 2):

With TikZ:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\diamondrulelength}
\setlength{\diamondrulelength}{0.6\textwidth}
\newlength{\diamondrulethickness}
\setlength{\diamondrulethickness}{2pt}
\newcommand{\diamondrule}{\begin{center}\tikz{\fill[black] (0.5\diamondrulelength,0) -- (0,0.5\diamondrulethickness) -- (-0.5\diamondrulelength,0) -- (0,-0.5\diamondrulethickness) -- cycle;}\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\diamondrule

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can at least do it with some TikZ keys instead of blocking two more registers. Use `\centering` in a group instead center environment.

Comment: @astrinus Would you be able to print an output of this code?