# Chapter title with decorative separator

Tags: decorations

Where can I find the decorative separator pictured here?

[image]

I want to add it to the (nearly complete) chapter title below. Note: the program I use (Latexian) has the most common packages installed, but doesn't let you load new ones (as far as I know). For example, I can't use pgfornaments.

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-5em}% Space above number
    {\parindent \z@  \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE\centering \textbf{\itshape\thechapter}%
    \par\vspace{0.5em}% Space between number and title
    {\LARGE\itshape#1}%
    \par\vspace{4em}% Space between title and text
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you searching the line element?

Comment: Yes, the line element.

Comment: Maybe the following is of interest: [Totally sweet horizontal rules in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76547)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I couldn't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Is the decorative line supposed to have a variable length in function of the chapter title width, or a fixed width?

Comment: Variable would be best, but I can work with fixed.

Comment: Latexian is just an editor. It has nothing to do with which packages are installed and it doesn't get to decide whether you can install more of them or not. The download instructions tell you to install MacTeX or BasicTeX i.e. the standard distribution of TeX Live for Mac OS X. If `pgfornaments` or whatever has what you want, just install it. Latexian doesn't have anything to do with it: it is just executing binaries from the TeX distribution under the hood. Those will be able to use whatever packages you have installed, including ones not in TeX Live and including any you write yourself.

Comment: Related: [PRL style horizontal line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130762/5764)

Comment: @Werner Is this a duplicate, do you think?

Comment: @cfr: The post is only requesting a reproduction of the "rule", so I would say yes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your choice of editor does not affect the packages you can install. You can update your TeX distribution, install additional packages, classes and fonts, and create your own independent of your editor. Your editor does not, that is, stop you using `pgfornaments` and I'm assuming nothing else does, so if you like its decorations, you should certainly install and use it.

`decorule` offers a decorative, swelled rule which does not depend on the installation of additional ornaments or fonts. Instead, it creates the rule from a character included in all TeX distributions. However, the results are predictably somewhat less satisfying than a proper typographic decoration might be.

[image: decorative rule]

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-5em}% Space above number
    {\parindent \z@  \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE\centering \textbf{\itshape\thechapter}%
    \decorule
    \par\vspace{0.5em}% Space between number and title
    {\LARGE\itshape#1}%
    \par\vspace{4em}% Space between title and text
}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{decorule}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}

\end{document}
```

Or you could try `swrule`. Again, no special stuff needs to be installed. However, I've never managed to produce satisfactory results:

[image: swelled rule]

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-5em}% Space above number
    {\parindent \z@  \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE\centering \textbf{\itshape\thechapter}%
    \par\vspace{0.25em}% Space between number and title
    \mbox{}\swrulex{.3\textwidth}{.25pt}{3.5pt}
    \par\vspace{0.25em}% Space between number and title
    {\LARGE\itshape#1}%
    \par\vspace{4em}% Space between title and text
}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{swrule}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}

\end{document}
```

If you don't mind the overhead, you could always draw one:

[image: drawn rule]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newsavebox{\myrule}
\sbox{\myrule}{\tikz {\path [fill, draw] (0,0) [out=0, in=180] to +(.125\textwidth,1pt) [out=0, in=180] to +(.125\textwidth,-1pt) [out=180, in=0] to +(-.125\textwidth,-1pt) [out=180, in=0] to cycle;}}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-5em}% Space above number
    {\parindent \z@  \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE\centering \textbf{\itshape\thechapter}%
    \par\vspace{0.25em}% Space between number and title
    \usebox{\myrule}%
    \par\vspace{0.25em}% Space between number and title
    {\LARGE\itshape#1}%
    \par\vspace{4em}% Space between title and text
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}

\end{document}
```

The advantage of creating `\myrule` as a box is that the TikZ picture only has to be rendered once for the document, regardless of how many times it is used. If, however, you want to be able to alter the length of the rule within the document, a command will work better:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\myrule[1][.25\textwidth]{%
  \tikz {\path [fill, draw] (0,0) [out=0, in=180] to +(.5*#1,1pt) [out=0, in=180] to +(.5*#1,-1pt) [out=180, in=0] to +(-.5*#1,-1pt) [out=180, in=0] to cycle;}}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-5em}% Space above number
    {\parindent \z@  \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE\centering \textbf{\itshape\thechapter}%
    \par\vspace{0.25em}% Space between number and title
    \myrule%
    \par\vspace{0.25em}% Space between number and title
    {\LARGE\itshape#1}%
    \par\vspace{4em}% Space between title and text
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}

\end{document}
```

Here, `\myrule` is `.25\textwidth` by default but `\myrule[some length]` will override that default. For example, `\myrule[.1\textwidth]` would produce

[image: shorter rule]

This can then be adapted to permit changing the length as appropriate in the document:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\myrule[1][.25\textwidth]{%
  \tikz {\path [fill, draw] (0,0) [out=0, in=180] to +(.5*#1,1pt) [out=0, in=180] to +(.5*#1,-1pt) [out=180, in=0] to +(-.5*#1,-1pt) [out=180, in=0] to cycle;}}
\newlength\myrulelength
\setlength{\myrulelength}{.1\textwidth}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-5em}% Space above number
    {\parindent \z@  \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE\centering \textbf{\itshape\thechapter}%
    \par\vspace{0.25em}% Space between number and title
    \myrule[\myrulelength]%
    \par\vspace{0.25em}% Space between number and title
    {\LARGE\itshape#1}%
    \par\vspace{4em}% Space between title and text
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\let\clearpage\relax% only for testing!

\chapter{Chapter title}

\setlength\myrulelength{.2\textwidth}
\chapter{Another chapter title}

\end{document}
```

[image: variable length rule]

To have the length automatically adapt depending on the length of the chapter title, you might try this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\myrule[1][.25\textwidth]{%
  \tikz {\path [fill, draw] (0,0) [out=0, in=180] to +(.5*#1,1pt) [out=0, in=180] to +(.5*#1,-1pt) [out=180, in=0] to +(-.5*#1,-1pt) [out=180, in=0] to cycle;}}
\newlength\myrulelength
\setlength{\myrulelength}{.1\textwidth}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-5em}% Space above number
    {\parindent \z@  \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE\centering \textbf{\itshape\thechapter}%
    \settowidth{\myrulelength}{\LARGE\itshape#1}%
    \par\vspace{0.25em}% Space between number and title
    \myrule[.8\myrulelength]%
    \par\vspace{0.25em}% Space between number and title
    {\LARGE\itshape#1}%
    \par\vspace{4em}% Space between title and text
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\let\clearpage\relax% only for testing!

\chapter{Chapter title}

\chapter{Another chapter title}

\end{document}
```

[image: auto-variable rule]

Comment: You have lot of patience. +1.

Comment: When I tried to use the second to last one, it wouldn't compile. Specifically, next to `\chapter{Chapter title}`, it gives the following errors: (1) "paragraph ended before tikz @ collect @ coordinate @ onpath was complete" and (2) "extra } or forgotten \endgroup". If you need more information I can provide it, but hopefully this will tell you what's going on.

Comment: @RandyRanderson Can you compile the example as included in my post i.e. that exact code? If so, then I'd need an example which produces the error. If not, then try putting `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` so we can compare the versions of files we're using. I just double-checked and the example compiles fine for me, so I can't tell what's wrong without more information as I can't reproduce the problem.