# Draw a decorative line thin - thick - thin

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

Does anybody know how you can draw a line, that starts very thin and then gets thick to the middle and then thin again? I hope this is clear because I cannot produce a minimal example here. 
I think this should be possible with tikz but any solution / suggestion would be welcome.

I would like to use it to separate the Author from the title on the titlepage.

Comment: You want a *swelled rule*: look at the manual of the `gmp` package. There are surely TikZ based methods, too.

Comment: Depending on your usage, the following might be a duplicate: [PRL style horizontal line in Latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130762/5764)

Comment: More decorated rules can be found in [`pgfornament`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfornament#page=20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways with tikz: using the `calligraphy` library (for pen like strokes), making a very thin losangle and a very thin ellipse.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum size=5cm]{};
\pen (0,0);
\calligraphy (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\fill (-1,-.25) -- ++(1,.1mm) -- ++(1,-.1mm) -- ++(-1,-.1mm) -- cycle;
\fill (0,-0.5) circle[x radius=1cm, y radius=.1mm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Ridicolous zoom:

[image]

Comment: You should move this answer to the one marked as duplicate

Comment: @egreg You think so? Is there a "formal" way to do it or just copy/paste/delete?