# Line with a changing width in the footer

Tags: header-footer

Is there a way to format the horizontal line in the footer so that it looks like this one?

[image]

I'm using the package `fancyhdr` to format the header and the footer.

Thank you!

Comment: Related: [PRL style horizontal line in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130762/5764)

Comment: And how this can be adapted to the `fancyhdr` package?

Comment: You can either modify fancyhdr to do what you want, or you can stop using fancyhdr.  Frankly, the second is easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resize a `\bullet` by squeezing/flattening it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \makebox[0pt][c]{\thepage}% Page number
  \makebox[0pt][c]{\raisebox{\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\resizebox{1.2\linewidth}{1pt}{$\bullet$}}}% Varied-width line
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```