# What is this symbol in LaTeX? And where do I get it?

Tags: sectioning, symbols

I'm referring to this symbol I find every now and then, in a book, to separate the first few initial paragraphs of a chapter from the rest.

[image]

Comment: This isn't a math symbol.  Properly, it's a "fleuron".  There was an [article in TUGboat](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb34-2/tb107glister.pdf) that covers that topic.  Although this exact symbol isn't included there, the article is worth reading as an introduction to the concept.

Comment: Related: [PRL style horizontal line in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130762/5764)

Comment: Obligatory link to the [One True Symbols List](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/)

Comment: @jessexknight, impressively the symbol I'm asking about might not be there. At least I'm pretty sure it's not listed as a _fleuron_.

Comment: @Enlico Blasphemy!

Comment: Checkout this Link <https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols> <br>It has a list of Latex Symbols and how to use them.

Comment: The first thing would be to check which font the book uses. Otherwise your question boils down to drawing the character.

Answer (score 34):

It's hard to judge the scale of your fleuron, but you can design something similar using the Ti*k*Z `calligraphy` library.

In the code below, the `\pen` command defines the angle (30°) and width (2mm) of a "calligraphic pen". The `\calligraphy` command works like `\draw` except using the defined pen. You can adjust the design however you like.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calligraphy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pen (0,0) -- (30:.2);
\calligraphy (0,0) to[out=30, in=210] ++(2,0)
            (30:.25)to[out=30, in=210] ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You may want to put this into a macro so you can use it repeatedly throughout the book. You can adjust the spacing above and below.

[image]

Change the `scale` factor to adjust size.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calligraphy}

\newcommand{\myfleuron}{\vspace{5mm}% <-- additional space above
    {\centering
    \tikz[baseline=-.68ex, scale=.15] % <-- adjust size of fleuron here]
    {\pen (0,0) -- (30:.2);
    \calligraphy (-1,0) to[out=30, in=210] ++(2,0)([xshift=-1cm]30:.25)to[out=30, in=210] ++(2,0);}
    \par}\vspace{5mm}% <-- additional space below
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\myfleuron

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

I used only PDF primitive operations to create the symbol. `\pdfliteral` primitive from pdftex is used. We need not TikZ.

```
The symbol: \pdfliteral{q 1 0 0 .8 5 0 cm
   0 0 m 20 10 40 10 50 0 c 60 -10 80 -10 90 -5 c
   70 -15 50 -12 40 0 c 30 12 15 5 0 0 c h f
   .8 0 0 1 -5 -3 cm
   0 0 m 20 10 40 10 50 0 c 60 -10 80 -10 90 -10 c
   70 -15 50 -12 40 0 c 30 12 15 5 0 0 c h f
Q}

\bye
```

[image: listecky]