# How to get a properly centred horizontal rule?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rules

I'm trying to produce a horizontal rule 2/3 the `textwidth` and centred. It's much harder than expected, as it pulls to the left. I've tried putting `noindent` but that makes it worse, as this MNWE shows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
This line is 2/3 textwidth with hspace\{stretch\} either side and no indent:

\noindent\hspace{\stretch{1}}\rule{0.67\textwidth}{0.1pt}\hspace{\stretch{1}}

This line is 2/3 textwidth with hspace\{stretch\} either side:

\hspace{\stretch{1}}\rule{0.67\textwidth}{0.1pt}\hspace{\stretch{1}}

This line is 4/5 textwidth with hspace\{stretch\} either side:

\hspace{\stretch{1}}\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.1pt}\hspace{\stretch{1}}

This line is 9/10 textwidth with hspace\{stretch\} either side:

\hspace{\stretch{1}}\rule{0.9\textwidth}{0.1pt}\hspace{\stretch{1}}

This line is full textwidth:

\hspace{\stretch{1}}\rule{\textwidth}{0.1pt}\hspace{\stretch{1}}

This line is full linewidth:

\hspace{\stretch{1}}\rule{\linewidth}{0.1pt}\hspace{\stretch{1}}

\end{document}
```

I've also tried just using `\hfill`s instead of the `\hspace{\stretch{1}}`s, but that produces the same effect. What am I missing?

Comment: After studying the various answers, I see what I missed. My real work uses scrbook which is setting ```\parindent0cm``` in some way or other, but that isn't operative here. When I added that at the start of my MNWE, it then looked fine. I was fooled because none of my text wrapped to a second line, and so the centering of text and rules looked different. Silly me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And a very short version: `\centerline{\rule{0.6667\linewidth}{.2pt}}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\parindent2cm

document document document document document
document document document document document
document document document document document
document document document document document
document document document document document

\centerline{\rule{0.6667\linewidth}{.2pt}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you; this is simple and effective. I'd not come across ```\centerline``` before; it doesn't seem to crop up often in tutorials.

Comment: @JGC `\centerline` is a plain TeX construction, so often omitted in LaTeX tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

The following example defines macro `\parseprule` for a rule that separates paragraphs with width of 2/3 the current line width (`\linewidth` takes into account lists). It also raises the line to approximately get in the middle between the paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\parseprule}{%
  \par
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \raisebox{.2\baselineskip}{%
      \rule{.6667\linewidth}{.4pt}%
    }%
    \par
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\par{\centering\raisebox{.2\baselineskip}{\rule{.9\linewidth}{.4pt}}\par}

\lipsum[2]

\parseprule

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- `\centering` does not insert vertical space as environment `center`.
- TeX uses the settings for a paragraph that are active at the end of the paragraph. Therefore the first `\par` is *outside* the group to end the previous paragraph not in the scope of `\centering`. The last `\par` is inside the group, because the paragraph with the rule should be centered.
- `\strut` as approximation for the height/depth ratio of a line uses `0.7\baselineskip` for the height and `0.3\baselineskip` for the depth. 
  Therefore the macro raises the line from the baseline to `0.2\baselineskip`.

### General remarks

- Paragraph indentation. TeX adds the space `\parindent` at the start of a new paragraph unless it is suppressed by `\noindent`. `\centering` sets `\parindent` to `0pt`, thus it does not matter, if the paragraph starts with `\noindent` or not.
- At the paragraph end, TeX removes a preceding horizontal skip space. Usually this is the space by the end of line. If the paragraph ends with `\hfill` then it is removed. Then TeX inserts `\parfillskip`. Default is `0pt plus 1fil`, that allows that the text of the last line does not need to fill the space.
- Each line gets the spaces `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` at both ends, usually they are zero, but this can change in lists, for example. `\centering` uses them for centering the line by setting them both to `0pt plus 1fil`.

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\noindent\hfil\rule{.666\linewidth}{.4pt}\hfill

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the `\hfill`at the end gets eaten (and replaced with `\parfilskip`), henc is superfluous; in fact, if this were not the case, it would be stronger than the `\hfil`in the beginning!

Answer (score 2):

You need to play around with the indentation lengths:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

This line is 2/3 \verb|\textwidth| with \verb|\hfill| either side and \verb|\noindent|:

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\hfill\rule{.6667\textwidth}{.4pt}\hfill}

This line is 2/3 \verb|\textwidth| with \verb|\hfill| either side without \verb|\noindent|:

\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-\parindent]{\hfill\rule{.6667\textwidth}{.4pt}\hfill\hspace*{\parindent}}

Also see:

\mbox{}\hfill\rule{.6667\linewidth}{.4pt}\hfill\hspace*{\parindent}

\end{document}
```

Note that while I mention `\textwidth`, I actually use `\linewidth`. As such, the above will change if you're calling it from inside a list environment where margins have been adjusted.

If you're going to use this often as some form of textual divider, I suggest following the advice in [Consistent typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764) and create a macro to house the rule.

The above can be combined with [Totally sweet horizontal rules in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76514/5764).