# Separation between paragraphs on formal Letters

Tags: letters, letterspacing

I want to create a formal letter in which I have to add a separator between paragraphs, just as the ones in the picture [image: Example]

Is there a way to create a this but not by typing each asterisk below the paragraph?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xhfill}

\begin{document}

\typein[\secretarioacademico]{Ingrese el nombre del secretario academico.}

QUIEN SUSCRIBE, \textbf{\MakeUppercase{\secretarioacademico}}\\
SECRETARIO ACADEMICO DE LA DIVISION DE INGENIERIAS CAMPUS IRAPUATO-SALAMANCA DE LA UNIVERSIDAD DE GUANAJAUTO, \textbf{HACE CONSTAR} QUE:\xdotfill{1pt}
\vspace{2cm}

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You may be interested in this too: [Totally sweet horizontal rules in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32711)

Comment: Hi, I already checked it but I find the package xhfill but is not what I expected. The others ones are not quite what I am looking for. I will keep looking. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your question. All questions should include a small, complete document people can compile to play with and which shows what you have tried so far. What, for example, is 'not what you expected' and why are the others 'not quite what you are looking for'? You have not given people much to go on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure whether this is what you might be after. Moreover, you probably don't want this kind of separation between *every* paragraph:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\parline}{\par\noindent{\centering\makebox[.3\linewidth][s]{* * * * * * * * * * * * *}\par}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\parline

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

You can adjust the width `.3\linewidth` to suit your needs. For example, using `.6\linewidth` results in:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It is quite similar of what I was looking at. I am going to use it. :D