# Placing a decorative separator in text

Tags: text-decorations

How do I put a decorative separator (like three asterisks or other symbols) in a text document so as to separate two sections of text, but not in a way that depends on LateX `\section` commands?

Such symbols used to be relatively common in books, but seem less common now.

NOTE: The proposed duplicate says "I would like to use a symbol", and the answers mostly reflect that. But I don't care if the decorative separator is a single symbol; in fact, it is better if it isn't. So, this question is more general than that one.

Comment: You can find interesting ways to put _cool_ separators here (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32711/totally-sweet-horizontal-rules-in-latex/76555)

Answer (score 14):

Most people just put some nice symbols in a `center` environment, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\lipsum\[1\]
\begin{center}
  $\ast$~$\ast$~$\ast$
\end{center}
\lipsum\[2\]
\begin{center}
  $\clubsuit$~$\clubsuit$~$\clubsuit$
\end{center}
\lipsum\[3\]
\end{document}][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

### First option using `memoir` class

The `memoir` class provides the `\plainbreak` and `\fancybreak` commands for this purpose (see the manual, `texdoc memoir`, pp. 99-101). There is also a `\plainfancybreak` command that will omit the fancy symbols if the break occurs at the top of a page.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\starbreak}{%
    \fancybreak{* * *}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\plainbreak{2}

\lipsum[2]

\starbreak

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Second option for any class

To add to @Boris's answer, you can use the `psvectorian` package to access many beautiful ornaments that are well suited to this purpose.

Here I define two commands: the first just puts ornaments as a break in the text; the second puts a header text plus ornaments.

The `psvectorian` package allows you to include beautiful PostScript illustrations, which are listed by number in the documentation (`texdoc psvectorian`, in French but the examples are in LaTeX). The basic command is `\psvectorian[width=1em]{2}` where the `{2}` specifies that you want image 2 as listed in the documentation.

You can either include them directly as in this example (which, because it uses PostScript, must be compiled with `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf`, not with `pdflatex`). Or you can compile the graphics separately (e.g., using the `standalone` package) and just use `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package to include them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{psvectorian}

\newcommand{\ornamentleft}{%
    \psvectorian[width=2em]{2}%
}
\newcommand{\ornamentright}{%
    \psvectorian[width=2em,mirror]{2}%
}
\newcommand{\ornamentbreak}{%
    \begin{center}
    \ornamentleft\quad\ornamentright
    \end{center}%
}
\newcommand{\ornamentheader}[1]{%
    \begin{center}
    \ornamentleft
    \quad{\large\emph{#1}}\quad % style as desired
    \ornamentright
    \end{center}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\lipsum[1]

\ornamentbreak

\lipsum[2]

\ornamentheader{Header but not a section command}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is that TeX sees a feasible page break point before the ornament.

Comment: @egreg Wouldn't that be a good thing?

Comment: No, the ornament should not go at the top of a page.

Comment: @egreg Oh, I see; that's true for the ornament-only break. The text-plus-ornament break seems to me just like another header, which can move to the top of the page. `memoir` includes a `\plainfancybreak` command just to avoid that problem.

Comment: @egreg Is there an easy workaround?

Comment: took me a while to figure that out but the compilation of psvectorian cannot be done using pdflatex unless adding

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}


and activating --shell-escape

Answer (score 8):

there are two tugboat articles that deal with ornaments that can be used as separators
in a way that is not tied to sectioning.

- [peter flynn, typographers' inn, *tugboat* 31:1 (2010)](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-1/tb97inn.pdf)
- [peter wilson, glisterings, *tugboat* 32:2 (2011)](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-2/tb101glister.pdf)