# How to add separator between paragraphs (or minipages) on the same page?

Tags: paragraphs, minipage, rules

I am trying to typeset a list of quotations in the following way:

1. No quotation is split across pages.
2. Between adjacent quotations on the same page, there is a separator (such as a fleuron or horizontal rule).

Note that, in particular, I do not want a rule after the last quotation on a given page.

I'd like to create a command that outputs a quotation and adds a rule only if a quotation follows (or precedes) it.  How could I go about this?

Comment: Should the first quotation on a page be preceded by a fleuron (or something similarly decorative)?

Comment: this question in turn points to two others: [Placing a decorative separator in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237110/579)

Comment: The separator should only appear between quotations; not before the first or after the last on any page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule used in `\leaders`:

```
\leaders \hrule \vskip.4pt
```

is removable like another space on the page breaks. You can define somethig like this:

```
\raggedbottom
\newcount\quotnumber
\def\quotation{\par\global\advance\quotnumber by1
   \bigskip
   \ifnum\qoutnumber>1 \leaders \hrule \vskip.4pt \bigskip \fi
   \vbox
}

The introduction text.
\quotation{text of first quotation}
\quotation{text of second quotation}
etc.
\bye
```

The removable rule is placed before `\vbox` with quotation because we needn't to have the rule after the last quotation. The test "if it is the first quotation" is used because we needn't the rule between introduction text and the first quotation.

Comment: Thy is my first time asking a question here, and I see I didn't give enough information.  I'm using LaTeX.  If I use a counter to detect the first quotation on a page, how can I detect the page break?  (Since quotations are formatted with minipages, they will never span pages.)

Comment: @JacobSmullyan OK, if you are using minipage then you can remove the last command `\vbox` from the definition of `\quotation` and you can use: `\quotation \begin{minipage}...\end{minimage}` `\quotation\begin{minipage}...\end{minipage}`. This looks more like LaTeX, isn't it? But `\vbox` does roughly the same as `minipage` environment.

Comment: I've had mixed success so far in getting /leaders to work.  If the separator is an hrule, your solution works nicely; if I want to follow /leaders with something else, it never appears.  E.g., using \leaders\hbox to \textwidth{\hfil \psvectorian[width=2em]{2} \hfil} \vskip.5pt \bigskip, nothing appears.

Comment: @JacobSmullyan Maybe your `\hbox to` has a width greater than `.5pt`, so it cannot fit into this very little space. You can check this and you can use `\cleaders` instead `\leaders` in such situation. If this doesn't solve your problem you can open new question and give your MWE because it seems to be somewhat different problem than the previous.

Comment: That fixed it, as I should have seen immediately.