# Three Dots in Center Page

Tags: sectioning, positioning

For some books, authors can use three dots in the middle of a page to signify when a section ends and another begins without an explicit sextion header. This is demonstrated in the excerpt below:

[image]

Focusing on the three stars in the center of the page, I wonder how one can do something like that in LaTeX.

And to be more specific, where can I find options for different symbols? Previous questions look at certain packages. I am wondering if there is a repository of possibilities.

I have tried using a `\section{}` command but it does not seem to be the best option.

Thank you!

Comment: This might be helpful: [Placing a decorative separator in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237110/579)

Comment: Is it natural that 3 dots is at the center of page? It should be in between ending of the curent section and the next section, right?

Comment: `\[\dots\]` :P.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you don't you need a machinery like TikZ for that:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\newcommand{\threestars}{\begin{center}$ {\ast}\,{\ast}\,{\ast} $\end{center}}

\newcommand{\varthreestars}{\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{c}$\ast$\\[-0.8ex] $\ast\enspace \ast $\end{tabular}\end{center}}

\begin{document}

 \lipsum[1]
 \threestars
 \lipsum[2]
 \varthreestars
 \lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since `\ast` is a `\mathbin`, simply saying `$\ast\ast\ast$` gives three spaced-out asterisks… ;o)

Comment: I know. I just thought they were a bit too much spaced (for my taste ;o))

Answer (score 4):

TikZ may help in this case.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1]
\vspace*{2mm}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\textwidth/2} 
\path (0,0); % move pen to (0,0) left most of the text
\path (\a pt,0) node[scale=5,blue]{$\cdots$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{2mm}

\lipsum[1-1]
\vspace*{5mm}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\textwidth/2} 
\path (0,0); % move pen to (0,0) left most of the text
\path[every node/.style={star,draw,fill=magenta,star point ratio=2.5,scale=.5}] 
(\a pt,0) node{}--+(0:1) node{}--+(180:1) node{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{5mm}

\lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `memoir` class provides for a variety of anonymous breaks (no number, no title text) in a document.

```
\plainbreak{<num>} % insert <num> blank lines
\fancybreak{<text>} % insert <text> 
% e.g., \fancybreak{{*}\\{* * *}\\{*}} % insert a diamond shape made of asterisks
\plainfancybreak{<space>}{<num>}{<text>} % insert <num> blank lines in the
% midle of a page or <text> if at the top or bottom
```

For full details see section **6.7 Fancy anonymous breaks** in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`) which also provides a range of ideas for such breaks.