# How to typeset a thematic break?

Tags: typography, semantics

[In HTML5, the `<hr>` tag defines a thematic break.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp) How can I do this in Latex? **I would prefer a semantic solution.**

Comment: Thematic break? It is *Horizontal Rule*.

Comment: Not in HTML 5. Of course, most browsers display it as a horizontal rule anyway.

Comment: Not a duplicate, I'm looking for something *semantic*.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32711/15925

Comment: This question is still not clear. What does "semantic" mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own command:

```
\newcommand{\thematicbreak}{\par\bigskip}
```

If you want a horizontal rule, decoration, asterism, etc., you can do that, too (as explained in [Totally sweet horizontal rules in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32711/totally-sweet-horizontal-rules-in-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1)). Here's a simple version:

```
\newcommand{\thematicbreak}{\begin{center}* * *\end{center}}
```

Or, following the default display of `<hr>` (which, let's be real, originated as an abbreviation for "horizontal rule"):

```
\newcommand{\thematicbreak}{\par\bigskip\noindent\hrulefill\par\bigskip}
```

`<thematic break>`

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\thematicbreak}{\par\bigskip\noindent\hrulefill\par\bigskip}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\thematicbreak
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small code for an `asterism` I use from time to time:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\asterism}{%
\vspace{2.5ex}\par\noindent%
\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering{*}\\[-4pt]{*}\enspace{*}\vspace{2ex}}\par%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\asterism
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I know why this downvote?

Comment: No downvote (but +1)  from me, but we have some strange users here as well