# Is there this ornament in latex?

Tags: ornamental-fonts

I am trying to find latex ornaments similar to these.
[image: Ornament 1]
[image: Ornament 2]

I checked out [pgfornaments](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/pgfornament/doc/ornaments.pdf) and [The comprehensive latex symbol list](http://caesar.ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), but could not find anything that looked close enough. Is there something similar that I overlooked? I want something to separate sections, so suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: not exactly the same, but `fourier` has some decorative elements suitable to separate sections. For example `\decofourleft` and `\decofourright`

Comment: you can include exactly that image as an image if you wish. Not everything has to be done in tikz or with fonts

Comment: You also can take a look at the `pst-vectorian`package, which has some ornaments in a similar spirit.

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32711 ?

Comment: Thanks. I will probably include the image directly like David Carlisle suggested