# Come back from a subsection

Tags: sectioning, indentation

I would like in a Latex document making a sub-section and then go back to the level of the section. But I can find out how to do it.

So my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
%\usepackage{pdfpages} 
%\usepackage[lined]{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage{moreverb}

\begin{document}
\section{deal}
\subsection{Paramétrisation du tracé}
Il faut faire attention aux valeurs rentrer par l'utilisateur dans ces champs, effectivement
beaucoup de valeurs sont à exclure. Les premières valeurs à exclure, sont à exclure pour tous les
paramètres, il s'agit de tout ce qui n'est pas des nombres.
\subsubsection{Range}
Les valeurs des différents range ($x$ et $y$) doivent absolument être des valeurs positives, car un
range négatif n'a aucun sens.
\subsubsection{Center}
Tous nombres entrés est acceptable comme valeurs.
\subsubsection{Step}
Ici, comme pour le range, seules des valeurs positives peuvent être acceptées.
%there I want to come back to the level of the section
Afin de signaler ces erreurs, le programme utilise le module \emph{tkMessageBox} et affiche donc
des \emph{showwarning} afn de signaler à l'utilisateur ses erreurs.
\end{document}
```

PS: I'm french so sorry for the french text.

Comment: Would some extra white-space or a typographic sign (like a fleuron or three asterisks) be a satisfactory option for you? Then one could create a command that does it (seeing as you can't "end" a subsection semantically).

Comment: Yes of course it would be great

Comment: See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11320/10119).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fourier-orns}

\newcommand{\fleuron}{
    \par\nopagebreak
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
        \centering\bigskip\aldineleft\par\bigskip
    }
}

\newcommand{\ornament}{
    \par\nopagebreak
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
        \centering\bigskip$\ast$\par$\ast\quad\ast$\par\bigskip
    }
}

\begin{document}

\section{A Section}

\lipsum[1]

\subsection{A Subsection}

\lipsum[2]

\fleuron

\lipsum[3]

\ornament

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image: Fleuron]

[image: Asterism]

Note that the [`lipsum` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) is only used to create dummy text (quite useful when you write a MWE). The [`fourier-orns` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fourier) is used by the first command (`\fleuron`), but there are other available packages. And the second command (`\ornament`) uses math mode to get the asterisks right because it is easier than in text mode.

Normally, the `\parbox` should prevent page breaks in the middle of the ornaments.

You can change the amount of vertical space (which is currently `\bigskip`) to `\midskip` or `\smallskip`, or even to an arbitrary length via `\vspace{<length>}`.

Comment: @kasmanit I have added the links in my answer. Both packages are on CTAN and I think they must ship with most distributions.

Comment: Ok I see the link but I don't catch how to install it (sorry gor thaht)

Comment: @kasmanit Did you try to compile it and got a warning? If you click "visit fourier's CTAN directory", you get [there](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fourier-GUT) and you can download a zip file that contains everything. Then you have to copy the folders and their contents to your local `texmf` directory (there is a read-me file inside). Where to create that folder depends on your operating system, but I am sure there are plenty of tutorials out there. Which OS are you using?

Comment: I'm running on OpenSuse. I'm searching now for my textmf directory so I can try this way

Comment: I create a texmf in my home direcotry but when I run "make" it's saying : 
`You want to install the fourier fonts
The location of the choosen TEXMF tree may be specified at the launch
of the MakeFile, now "make TGM=HOMETEXMF"
(you can choose  HOMETEXMF, TEXMFLOCAL or TEXMFMAIN).
So I will install in .
BUT this TEXMF tree does not exist`

Comment: @kasmanit Yes, on all systems, you eventually need to create that directory yourself… but unfortunately, I don't know much about your OS, so I won't be much help here.