# cleanest way to part answers from questions

Tags: best-practices, comments

I am still typesetting old exams, and I turn to you lads and lassies for help. At the moment I have most of the actual exams typed in, and is currently typing in answers for them.

The problem I run into is that it is quite hard distinguishing the actual exam questions and notes from the solutions.

Now I was thinking of ways to make them different enough, but not so different that it becomes a eyesore reading it. My thoughts was to either alter the text ever so slightly or, tint the background. Perhaps in a relaxing colour, perhaps beige. I guess another way is to add vertical lines or some other form of clear border. 
Or do nothing at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe} % new package from Martin scharrer
\usepackage{lipsum,caption,mathtools}
\usepackage{comment}
\includecomment{Answer}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}

\section*{Problem 1}

\paragraph*{a) } Prove that donkeys can fly if and only if they have more arms than penguins. \medskip

\begin{Answer}
\lipsum[1]
%
 \begin{figure}[!htbp]
 \centering
 \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
 \centering
        \includegraphics[width=3.0in]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Caption for image}
        \label{fig:some figure to accompany the answers}
 \end{minipage}
 \end{figure}
%
 \lipsum[2]
Q.E.D
\end{Answer}

\newpage

\section*{Problem 2}

\paragraph*{a) } If $(x+y)^2=99$ and $x^2+y^2 = 11$ what is $x\cdot y$? \medskip

\begin{Answer}
\lipsum[2] 
\begin{align*}
(x+y)^2 & = 99 \\
x^2 + y^2 + 2x\cdot y & = 99 \\
x\cdot y & = 44 \\
\end{align*} 
 \lipsum[3]
Q.E.D \medskip
\end{Answer}

Now is it posible finding $x-y$ from the information above? \medskip

\begin{Answer}
\lipsum[6]
Therefore it is not possible finding $x-y$ from the information given.
\end{Answer}

\end{document}
```

Here is an MWE, my actual code is more complicated but I guess this will do.

**My question is** Is it preferable to distinguish the answers and questions further, and if yes; what is the best way to do so?

Comment: I'd recommend putting the answers within an `mdframed` with a light background color and frame. Or you could use some kind of ornament to separate the question from the answer such as [End of paragraph with ornament](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11320/end-of-paragraph-with-ornament).

Comment: @Peter Grill 
I liked the idea of using mdframed, for an example I think
    \mdfdefinestyle{mystyle}{leftmargin=0pt,%
linecolor=Lavender,backgroundcolor=Ivory}
Looks good, but the problem is with the figures? I guess I could start and stop the mdframed, but that would look weird, and I would preffer a somewhat more automated solution.

Comment: You have to choose darker colors for the lines on the figures.  I have figures on top of frames with a background color and they show up just fine.

Comment: I am going to bed now. Will study this tomorow, but clearly [this](http://pastebin.com/jEpf8MZV) does not work.

Comment: Have you considered the exam style yet? It gives solution-groups a gray background. Personally I like the exams it produces a lot.

Answer (score 4):

This is a subjective question, so I don't think that you'll get a universal answer. Personally, I find documents typeset by TeX to be too err... professional, or rather too formal, which is not always a good thing.

Personally, I like to use background colors and frames to make the answers stand out; and to randomize the frame a bit so that it doesn't look too boring. See this [article](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/mahajan/) in PracTeX Journal for details. As an example, below is the example file included in the article (please ignore the typo in the solutions!)

[image]

Comment: For some reason or the other your link doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: PracTeX journal's webpage is down at the moment: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/

Comment: In fact, tug.org is down: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60878/323