# If tug.org is down, where can I download TexLive?

Tags: texlive

If tug.org is down, where can I download/update TeX-Live?

Comment: There are mirrors of CTAN (which includes TeX Live all over the world)

Answer (score 11):

never download tex live from tug.org (it's a source not an archive).
don't download tex live from dante or cambridge; we both have bandwidth allowance calculated to support mirroring only.

download tex live from

http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive

no other url.

Comment: Does it have the windows installer? (I can't find it at the moment on tug website. Btw - is it just me, or is tug's website the worst  simplest website in the world? I mean it just has to provide 2 Download Links: Linux and Windows.)

Answer (score 2):

tug.org may be offline at the moment due to power management work at Aarhus University (where tug.org is hosted). Should be up again during the weekend

Comment: More of a comment than an answer?