# Environment for writing solutions in amsbook

Tags: exam, amsbook

Basically, what I want is exactly asked in [Showing Solutions of the Questions "separately"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15350/showing-solutions-of-the-questions-separately), except that I'm using `amsbook`. So, I want to write a series of questions, by writing something like

```
\begin{question}

\question 1+1=?

\begin{answer}
1+1=2
\end{answer}

\question What is 1+2=?

\begin{answer}
1+2=3
\end{answer}

\end{question}
```

The code above should display the questions only:

> Question 1: 1+1=?
>
> Question 2: 1+2=?

Then the command

```
\showanswers
```

displays the answers:

> Answer 1: 1+1=2
>
> Answer 2: 1+2=3

I also want the enumeration style "Question 1, Question 2, ..." to be customizable.

Comment: I think this might help. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60771/cleanest-way-to-part-answers-from-questions

Comment: I don't seem to find the answer to my question.

Comment: Another option, use the exercise.sty style file.  It will give you both an exercise and and answer environment.  You have the options of either one, both, or none.  I use this to put questions into beamer presentations with or without answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using the [`answers`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/answers) package.

You can toggle the answers appearing or not by using

```
\usepackage{answers}
```

to write the answers to a file (`answers.tex` in the code below) or

```
\usepackage[nosolutionfiles]{answers}
```

to show the answers in the document.

I've used the [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) package to create a list-type environment called `questions`, and defined the `\question` command as `\item` (although it doesn't take an optional argument- not sure if this matters or not here though).

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{enumitem}   % for custom lists
\usepackage{answers}    % for separating solutions
%\usepackage[nosolutionfiles]{answers}

\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[questions]{label*=Question \arabic*.}
\newcommand{\question}{\item}

% open the answer file
\Opensolutionfile{answers}
\Newassociation{answer}{ansWER}{answers}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question $1+1=?$
\begin{answer}
    $1+1=2$
\end{answer}

\question What is $1+2=?$
\begin{answer}
$1+2=3$
\end{answer}  
\end{questions}

% close the answer file
\Closesolutionfile{answers}

% use this line if you'd like to include the answers separately
\clearpage
\IfFileExists{answers.tex}{\input{answers.tex}}{no file!}
\end{document}
```

You can do a lot with the `answers` package, particularly if you combine it with the `hyperref`, as shown in a few answers on this site, for example in [Adding another answer hyperlinked to the question itself](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45670/adding-another-answer-hyperlinked-to-the-question-itself)