# Add Questions to chapters of an amsbook-based document

Tags: lists, amsbook

I am attempting to write an amsbook-based document (with chapters, and sections in each chapter).  I'd like a subsection at the end of each chapter with a list of problems for the reader to work on.

What's the cleanest way to accomplish this?

I found the following post, but it added an extreme margin to the left side of the text for each question, which is not what I wanted:  [Environment for writing solutions in amsbook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62715/environment-for-writing-solutions-in-amsbook?rq=1&newreg=0c82f7810f41496db5cdfc7c47b3fe37)

Comment: The link you provided is about providing both problems and answers. If I understand your setup correctly, you'll be providing "just" problems, but no answers. If this impression is correct, all you'd need to do is have an unnumbered `\subsection*{...}` directive, followed by a list of problems, at the end of each chapter.

Comment: @Mico  Thank you for welcoming me and for your answer.  I'd like to have the questions numbered, and for the first question of each chapter to be numbered one.   I'd also like the title of each question to be left justified and inlined with the text (though this is not necessary).  How can I achieve this?

Comment: there is a predefined environment `xcb` in `amsbook` that is meant for this situation.  please read the user documentation, which is the "ams author handbook" for monographs.  available on ctan, or from a link on the page https://www.ams.org/authors/author-handbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to have the questions numbered, and for the first question of each chapter to be numbered one. I'd also like the title of each question to be left justified and inlined with the text

I suggest you set up a dedicated enueration list (called `qq` below), using the machinery of the `enumitem` package. For "smart" cross-references to questions, I suggest using the `cleveref` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{qq}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[qq]{label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*,wide=0pt}

\usepackage{cleveref}  % load this package *last*
\crefname{qqi}{question}{questions} % text labels associated with question items

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\section{Hello}
\lipsum[2] % filler text
Cross-references to \cref{qq:bb,qq:dd}.

\section*{Questions}
\begin{qq}
\item Title of question 1. Body of question 1.
\item \label{qq:bb}Title of question 2. Body of question 2.
\item Title of question 3. Body of question 3.
\item \label{qq:dd} Title of question 4. Body of question 4.
\item Title of question 5. Body of question 5.
\end{qq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!
Two more requests.  Is it possible to have "Question 1." instead of "1." for the item label?  Also, could I have the chapter number as well?  So instead of "Question 1.", it would be something like "Question 3.1)" for the first question of chapter 3.

Also, how did you figure out how to do this?

Again, thank you so much!

Comment: @NicNic8 - To address your first two follow-up questions: Just change `\setlist[qq]{label=\arabic*., ref=\arabic*, wide=0pt}` to `\setlist[qq]{label=Question \thechapter.\arabic*), ref =\thechapter.\arabic*, wide=0pt}`. On your third follow-up question: I've been using LaTeX for more than 25 years. One of the (many!) nice things about LaTeX is that human capital invested in LaTeX doesn't depreciate appreciably over time; that's quite different from most commercial software experiences, isn't it?!