# Command ... unavailable in encoding EU1 when using unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

Because I cannot be dependent on a particular package (drm), I need to emulate it as best as possible, which works fine until I decide to load `unicode-math`.  Please consider this MWE which is cut so it only shows the error:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newcommand*{\drmsym}[1]%
  {\fontspec{drmsym10.otf}%
     [SizeFeatures=%
        {{Size={-7},Font=drmsym7.otf},
    {Size={8},Font=drmsym8.otf},
    {Size={9},Font=drmsym9.otf},
    {Size={10-12},Font=drmsym10.otf},
    {Size={12-14},Font=drmsym12.otf},
    {Size={14-17},Font=drmsym14.otf},
    {Size={17-24},Font=drmsym17.otf},
    {Size={24-},Font=drmsym24.otf}}]%
  {#1}}

\providecommand*{\textdied}%
  {\drmsym{\char'144}}
\begin{document}
\textdied
\end{document}
```

When you compile this document using XeLaTeX you receive the error message `Command \textdied unavailable in encoding EU1`.
When I decide not to load `unicode-math` and only load `fontspec` the code works as expected, which seems to indicate that the former package alters the fontencoding somewhere. Does anyone know how to solve this issue while retaining the `unicode-math` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use neither `\fontspec` nor `\providecommand`:

- using `\fontspec` is not recommended, because very inefficient;
- `\textdied` already has a definition as a TS1 command when `unicode-math` is loaded, so `\providecommand does nothing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newfontface{\drmfont}{drmsym10}[
  Extension=.otf,
  SizeFeatures={
    {Size={-7.5},Font=drmsym7},
    {Size={7.5-8.5},Font=drmsym8},
    {Size={8.5-9.5},Font=drmsym9},
    {Size={9.5-11},Font=drmsym10},
    {Size={11-13},Font=drmsym12},
    {Size={13-15},Font=drmsym14},
    {Size={15-21},Font=drmsym17},
    {Size={21-},Font=drmsym24}
  }
]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\drmsym}{\normalfont\drmfont}
\UndeclareTextCommand{\textdied}{TS1}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textdied}{\drmsym{\symbol{'144}}}

\begin{document}

\textdied

\end{document}
```

I have changed the size choices, but it's not very important.

The `\UndeclareTextCommand` is used in order to avoid the original definition to kick in; `\normalfont` ensures shape and weight parameters are reset, so in an italic or boldface context the symbol will print anyway.

[image]