# Symbols that are usually put at the end of a paragraph

Tags: symbols

I'm looking for Latex command of the symbols that are usually put at the end of a paragraph. For example, it maybe a flower in this below image.

> [image]

Could you please inform me where to find such symbols?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free ornaments font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10941/free-ornaments-font)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some suitable fonts:

`pgfornament` available on CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfornament
[image: pgfornament]

`adforn` available on CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/adforn
[image: adforn]

See the manuals available on CTAN for the commands.
See [End of paragraph with ornament](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11320/end-of-paragraph-with-ornament) for shaping.