# How to Produce This Chapter Ornament Using PDFLATEX

Tags: graphics, pdftex, chapters

I would like to know how (if possible) to produce the following ornament using PDFLatex.

[image]

I obtained the image from a book that was published over one hundred years ago and would like to make use of it at the end of some of the chapters of a book I am currently typesetting.

Does LaTeX already have something similar to this? or can it be produced from scratch?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you in principle interested in ornaments (https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfornament, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10941) or only in the specific one that you provide in the question?

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuehner If I am not mistaken, I think those might require XeLatex to run and the document I am working on is using PDFLatex. I was hoping to use something very similar to the image I posted. Thank you.

Comment: I believe that u are mistaken, at least the `pgfornament` should work just fine since it is based on PGF/TikZ. Also, you might want to have a look at https://www.vectorian.net/free-vintage-vectors.html.

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuehner O.K. Thank you.

Comment: Not that ornament, but you can use others also from the  `fourier-orns` package. See for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74609/11604).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option is to redraw the ornament. Alternatively you can convert the png to pnm, and then use `potrace` to convert it to the svg format. For the example below I used

```
potrace -z black -b svg --tight myornament1.pnm
```

This will give you some svg paths that can be included e.g. via pgf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{svg.path}
\begin{document}
\begin{pgfpicture}
  \pgftransformscale{0.3}
  \pgfpathsvg{M600 600 c0 -29 -1 -30 -22 -16 -24 15 -118 33 -118 22 0 -3 20 -25
44 -49 78 -75 81 -140 10 -277 -18 -36 -37 -83 -42 -105 l-9 -40 76 -1 c78 -1
57 12 -24 15 -24 1 -35 5 -30 10 15 14 47 15 78 3 33 -14 96 -15 116 -3 7 5
23 6 35 3 17 -5 12 -8 -24 -18 l-45 -12 48 -1 c46 -1 47 -1 47 31 0 19 -9 41
-22 55 -20 21 -20 24 -5 41 10 10 17 23 17 28 -1 5 -11 -3 -23 -17 -15 -18
-36 -28 -64 -33 -24 -3 -43 -4 -43 -1 0 2 23 16 50 30 28 14 56 37 62 50 6 14
18 25 26 25 11 0 12 3 2 15 -6 8 -9 19 -5 25 7 12 -3 50 -14 50 -4 0 -13 -11
-19 -25 -15 -32 -101 -125 -115 -125 -6 0 9 21 34 48 70 72 98 122 68 122 -5
0 -8 -4 -5 -9 4 -5 3 -17 -1 -28 -6 -15 -9 -13 -14 12 l-8 30 2 -30 c1 -16 -5
-39 -13 -49 -39 -50 -74 -81 -91 -82 -10 -1 -19 -1 -19 0 0 0 9 25 20 54 33
88 21 161 -37 218 l-28 26 29 -7 c34 -7 86 -42 86 -56 0 -5 6 -9 13 -9 8 0 22
-9 32 -20 10 -11 23 -20 30 -20 7 0 17 -10 22 -22 11 -22 11 -22 18 -3 3 11
11 28 17 39 7 14 6 21 -4 27 -10 6 -15 -1 -19 -29 -5 -29 -6 -31 -8 -10 -1 31
-21 78 -32 78 -4 0 -1 -14 8 -31 8 -16 13 -33 10 -35 -11 -11 -60 31 -73 63
-20 46 -18 54 11 48 14 -3 35 -7 48 -10 12 -2 30 -18 41 -35 21 -36 32 -35 16
1 -18 40 -100 88 -100 59 0 -7 -6 -7 -20 0 -18 10 -20 8 -20 -20z m104 -266
c-13 -26 -36 -48 -73 -70 -57 -33 -82 -71 -34 -53 38 14 95 11 115 -8 22 -20
24 -35 3 -26 -9 3 -35 0 -59 -7 -35 -10 -52 -10 -81 0 -21 7 -33 15 -29 19 5
3 10 13 12 21 1 9 -5 6 -18 -8 -11 -13 -25 -22 -31 -20 -7 2 24 35 67 74 44
38 91 83 105 101 31 41 47 26 23 -23z m-148 -68 c12 4 5 -8 -20 -34 -22 -23
-42 -39 -45 -37 -2 3 6 16 19 30 13 14 18 25 12 25 -6 0 -9 7 -5 16 4 10 8 12
13 4 4 -6 15 -8 26 -4z}
  \pgfpathsvg{M187 600 c-36 -28 -40 -48 -22 -115 13 -51 13 -60 0 -78 -8 -12 -15
-28 -15 -37 1 -8 7 -1 14 15 l13 30 0 -43 c0 -54 23 -86 91 -131 29 -19 51
-36 49 -38 -8 -7 -112 45 -130 65 -10 11 -22 33 -28 48 -9 28 -9 27 -4 -5 3
-19 13 -43 22 -53 16 -17 15 -20 -5 -34 -16 -11 -22 -25 -22 -52 l0 -38 61 -2
c33 -2 64 -3 67 -3 28 -4 112 3 112 9 0 4 -49 7 -109 7 -102 0 -134 6 -118 22
4 3 31 0 60 -7 37 -8 67 -10 98 -3 57 11 92 6 85 -13 -3 -9 1 -14 14 -14 16 0
20 6 19 33 -1 25 -3 27 -6 8 -4 -19 -14 -5 -48 70 -25 52 -44 102 -45 111 0 9
-4 19 -9 23 -12 7 6 -60 26 -98 20 -40 10 -44 -17 -7 -53 75 -75 202 -45 260
18 36 66 62 103 58 l27 -3 -30 -18 c-50 -30 -75 -76 -74 -133 l1 -49 8 55 c7
48 14 60 58 101 28 26 54 44 58 41 4 -4 5 0 2 8 -11 35 -97 23 -135 -18 l-25
-27 7 36 7 36 -45 1 c-31 2 -52 -4 -70 -18z m69 -7 c-6 -15 -4 -15 14 2 24 21
26 8 6 -40 -13 -29 -41 -55 -61 -55 -4 0 -4 12 -1 26 5 17 3 23 -4 19 -15 -9
-13 -65 3 -65 7 0 23 7 35 16 22 15 22 15 22 -35 0 -28 7 -71 16 -97 8 -25 13
-48 11 -50 -11 -11 -56 67 -59 101 -2 27 -8 39 -20 41 -12 1 -18 -5 -19 -19 0
-21 -1 -21 -8 -2 -5 11 -11 38 -15 60 -5 31 -4 36 4 25 10 -13 11 -13 7 0 -2
8 -10 14 -16 13 -15 -4 -14 9 5 35 26 37 92 58 80 25z m-26 -175 c0 -19 -2
-20 -10 -8 -13 19 -13 30 0 30 6 0 10 -10 10 -22z m64 -143 c38 -38 62 -61 53
-49 -23 29 -21 41 3 19 11 -10 20 -14 21 -9 0 5 4 -1 9 -14 13 -31 2 -56 -17
-40 -10 8 -17 8 -21 1 -13 -19 -72 -23 -117 -7 -25 8 -50 12 -55 9 -14 -9 -12
9 2 23 17 17 73 15 109 -3 33 -18 57 -11 39 10 -6 8 -33 28 -59 44 -51 33 -71
65 -70 109 l0 27 17 -25 c9 -14 48 -56 86 -95z m-44 73 c0 -6 -7 -5 -15 2 -8
7 -15 17 -15 22 0 6 7 5 15 -2 8 -7 15 -17 15 -22z m75 -86 c-7 -7 -45 29 -45
41 0 6 11 0 25 -13 14 -13 23 -26 20 -28z} 
  \pgfpathsvg{M429 543 c-5 -16 -15 -41 -22 -58 -17 -41 -12 -190 7 -245 l16 -45
-6 45 c-4 25 -10 65 -14 90 -8 48 0 116 24 193 16 50 12 66 -5 20z}
  \pgfpathsvg{M475 540 c24 -113 25 -135 11 -225 -4 -27 -4 -34 3 -20 26 59 20 205
-10 255 -7 11 -8 8 -4 -10z}
  \pgfpathsvg{M622 488 c2 -16 6 -24 11 -19 5 5 5 17 -2 28 -9 16 -10 15 -9 -9z}
  \pgfpathsvg{M621 439 c-1 -10 -15 -43 -32 -75 -24 -46 -26 -54 -10 -40 24 22 55
99 48 118 -4 9 -6 8 -6 -3z}
  \pgfusepath{stroke,fill}
\end{pgfpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, using different parameters in the `potrace` conversion yield different results, and you can also use `potrace` to produce some vector graphics that you include via `\includegraphics` etc. Another option is to use `inkscape`.

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. When I try to run it, although I am able to produce the image, I get error messages along the lines of ``unexpected character `blank space' in parser `svgpath' in state `initial'  13 4 -4 etc. ---on line items that seem to contain the \pgfpathsvg commands. Any idea what may be wrong on my end? But strangely, again, I am able to produce the image with these messages. Thank you again.

Comment: +1: Unrelated, I believe that Inkscape already uses potrace (https://inkscape.org/doc/tutorials/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html): `"Currently Inkscape employs the Potrace bitmap tracing engine" `.

Comment: @mlchristians I really don't know, I do not get any errors either with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`. (I did update my TeXLive2021 installation a few weeks ago. This did break a few things, but none of them are related to pgf. So maybe an update may resolve the issue.)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thanks! I haven't used inkscape in a while.

Comment: @user242026 Yes, it could be because of the version of Latex I am using. Thanks again.